# $\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}=50$ Riemann-Zeta

Tags: riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I've to find a value for 's' were the infinit sum gives me the value 50. Is that possible and how do I've to calculate that value.

I've no idea how te begin so, help me!

Solve s for:

$$\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}=50$$

(and I know that it's the Riemann zeta function for real numbers bigger than 1)

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Comment: Approximative solution: We have $\lim_{s\to 1}(s-1)\zeta(s) = 1$ so $\zeta(s) \approx \frac{1}{s-1}$ for $s$ close to $1$. $s=1 + \frac{1}{50} = 1.02$ turns out to be pretty close to the true result. You want any better then you can try a higher order expansion or more simply: a numerical solution.

Comment: I am working on a project, where I've to use it! If it is possible

Comment: A quick plot in Mathematica shows me, that this is (probably) not possible. The values of that function are all below, at least, 5.

Comment: @StefanPerko : Not if $s$ goes to $1$ with $s < 1$.

Comment: @StefanPerko That is an artefact in the plot. For $s=1$ the sum is infinity and for $s=2$ the sum is $\pi^2/6 \approx 1.64$. The function is continuous inbetween so attains every value $> 1$ for some $s$.

Comment: @jibounet Oh yeah. Of course, where was my head...

Comment: There seems to be no motivation for this question. I mean you could at least admit that you don't care about the answer and that you only want to see methods to estimate it. That would at least make the question seem designed for people rather than computers....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have that the function $\zeta(s)$ is decreasing on the interval $(1,2)$. Since $\lim_{s\to 1^+}\zeta(s)=+\infty$ while $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}<50$ we have $\zeta(s_0)=50$ for some $s_0\in(1,2)$. Exploiting the asymptotic expansion in a right neighbourhood of $s=1$ (formula $(15)$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html), it follows from summation by parts) we have:
$$ \zeta(s)\approx \frac{1}{s-1}+\gamma $$
so a reasonable estimate for $s_0$ is given by:
$$ s_0\approx\frac{51-\gamma}{50-\gamma} $$
and we can increase the accuracy of such approximation by using Newton's method, for instance.

Comment: I like your answer but it's not a exact answer and that's what I would like to get. Is that possible?

Comment: @JanEerland: I wouldn't bet that a nice closed form for the solution exists.

Answer (score 6):

The Laurent series expansion of the Riemann Zeta function around $s=1$ is
$$\zeta(s) = \dfrac1{s-1} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!} \gamma_n (s-1)^n$$
Further, recall that since $\zeta(2) = \dfrac{\pi^2}6 < 50$ and since $\zeta(s)$ is a rapidly decreasing function close to $1$, we have $s \in (1,2)$. Approximating $\zeta(s)$ with the first three terms gives us a quadratic in $s$, i.e.,
$$\dfrac1{s-1} + \gamma_0 - \gamma_1(s-1) \approx 50$$
Solving the quadratic gives us $s \approx 1.020234186$. Better approximations can be obtained by considering more terms and solving the resulting polynomial equation using numerical root finding techniques.

Comment: Are $γ_n$ the Stieltjes constants?

Answer (score 4):

$$s\simeq1.0202341852181139861332276132729412593842116437344617189788796190\ldots$$

Comment: This does not seem to address "I've no idea how to begin so, help me!" other that perhaps pulling out a CAS.

Comment: @robjohn: *other that perhaps pulling out a CAS* - Precisely. There is no closed form for it. Numerical algorithms are the only way out.

Comment: @robjohn But that's exactly the point. In the comments OP said that the value of $s$ is only needed for calculation. The derivation of the answer is therefore irrelevant to the question at hand, at least it seems that way to me.

Comment: There are ways to get approximate answers without the black box of a CAS. Jack D'Aurizio's and user17762's answers give an idea of *how* to compute an approximation.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica yields 
$$s \approx 1.020234185218113986133227613272941259384211643734461718978879619075931...$$

I don't think you are going to get a good answer without just numerically approximating it.

Answer (score 2):

Since I have seen this graph for only real numbers ([source](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funkcja_dzeta_Riemanna#/media/File:Zeta_plot.gif))
[image]
- I have start thinking about to approximate the zeta function into a more elementary function: *Hyperbola*:

> $\zeta(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x} \rightarrow
>  H(x)=\frac{\alpha x+\beta}{\lambda x-x_0}+y_0$ for  x>1

To fit our hyperbola we gonna need [particular values of the Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function), like:

$(2;\frac{\pi^2}{6})$ and $(4;\frac{\pi^4}{90})$

One of the  *variables* for $H(x)$ is $x_0=1$

Of course $y_0$ should be $1$ but we gonna set $y_0=0$ and $\alpha=0$ as well.

Hense:
$h(x)=\frac{\beta}{\lambda x-1}$

> (For X variables we need (at least) X points to find our formula)

Result: $h(x)=\frac{\pi^4}{6}\frac{1}{30-\pi^2+\frac{4(\pi^2-15)}{x}}$ for $1<x<5.2$

Solving for $h(x)=50$ we get $x=\frac{4(\pi^2-15)}{\pi^2(\frac{\pi^2}{300}+1)-30}\approx1.036$ not really close but by this simplification is good.

> Epilog: A $H(x)$ can be fit for $x<1$ as well- here an example:

Via $(-1;-\frac{1}{12})$,$(0;-\frac{1}{2})$ and $(\frac{1}{2};\zeta(\frac{1}{2}))$ I have fit:

$h_2(x)=\frac{5(b+1)|x|}{12(b|x|+1)}-\frac{1}{2}$;where $b=\frac{17+24\zeta(\frac{1}{2})}{1+12\zeta(\frac{1}{2})}$;$x<1$