# Values of Riemann zeta at rational non-integer points

Tags: riemann-zeta

I would like to know do we have closed-form of Riemann zeta at at least one rational non-integer point such that that closed form contains already known constants and is not an infinite sum?

Comment: I'd say no, see particular values of [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Particular_values) (at $z= \pm 1$)

Comment: I don't know about $\zeta(s)$, but the logarithmic derivative $\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s)=\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ has a closed-form representation at least at one rational non-integer point which is $\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\gamma+\log (8 \pi)\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can create approximations as **hyperbolas**:

$\zeta(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x} \rightarrow
 H(x)=\frac{\alpha x+\beta}{\lambda x-x_0}+y_0$

One for x>1 and a different for x<1. To fit your formula you need some exist values.

For samples and more details please [read my feedback here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2907801/586889)